# Xamarin: The project 'Client' is unsupported

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I have sort of a problem with Xamarin. When I create new project "Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Shared)" in Visual Studio and build it right away without any modification I get an error

> The project 'Client' is unsupported

This error has no project nor file specified.

Nevertheless the project build successfully. Does anyone have any clue what this could mean and how can I get rid of this?

Comment: What kind of project is it?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? Do you have all the VS updates installed? Do you have a screen shot? Check the Visual Studio log and see if it has more information.

Comment: I have VS 2013.4 Premium. Screenshot is pointless, the error has no more info. File, line and column are blank.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot of your solution structure would help out?

Comment: After Xamarin update I cant reproduce this anymore.